# Adding policy attribute automatically in .net core web API

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi, asp.net-core-2.1

I'm using .net Core 2.1 Web API. I'm using action based authentication. So, I add every method `[Authorize(Policy = ".....")]` like below. But, I don't want write every time. I want taking policy name from method name automatically. How can I achieve this?

```
namespace University.API.Controllers
{
    [Route("api/[controller]")]
    [ApiController]
    public class UniversityController : ControllerBase
    {
        private readonly IUniversityService universityService;

        public UniversityController(IUniversityService universityService)
        {
            this.universityService = universityService;
        }

        [Authorize(Policy = "GetUniversities")]
        [HttpGet("GetUniversities")]
        public async Task<ServiceResult> GetUniversities()
        {
            return await universityService.GetUniversities();
        }

        [Authorize(Policy = "GetStudents")]
        [HttpGet("GetStudents")]
        public async Task<ServiceResult> GetStudents()
        {
            return await universityService.GetStudents();
        }

        [Authorize(Policy = "DeleteUniversity")]
        [HttpGet("DeleteUniversity")]
        public async Task<ServiceResult> DeleteUniversity(int universityId)
        {
            return await universityService.DeleteUniversity(universityId);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use a [custom convention](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/application-model?view=aspnetcore-2.1#conventions) for this, which allows for customisation of the [application model](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/application-model?view=aspnetcore-2.1). Using a convention allows you to add filters to each action within your project automatically, using either a global registration of said convention or by applying it using a attribute on the action, etc.

Here's a sample implementation of a custom convention for your purposes:

```
public class SomeActionModelConvention : IActionModelConvention
{
    public void Apply(ActionModel model)
    {
        model.Filters.Add(new AuthorizeFilter(model.ActionName));
    }
}
```

In this example, we implement [`IActionModelConvention`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.applicationmodels.iactionmodelconvention?view=aspnetcore-2.1), which defines an [`Apply`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.applicationmodels.iactionmodelconvention.apply?view=aspnetcore-2.1#Microsoft_AspNetCore_Mvc_ApplicationModels_IActionModelConvention_Apply_Microsoft_AspNetCore_Mvc_ApplicationModels_ActionModel_) method that is called by the MVC framework on initialisation. In the implementation above, we're simply adding an `AuthorizeFilter` to the model that uses the action's name as the policy name.

In order to register the convention, add it via `MvcOptions` in `Startup.ConfigureServices`. e.g.:

```
services.AddMvc(options => options.Conventions.Add(new SomeActionModelConvention()));
```

As I suggested above, it's possible to register this using an attribute, but that doesn't make much sense in this scenario as you'd have to add the attribute to the action itself, which would defeat the purpose of something high-level like this convention.

However, if you want to apply this as an attribute at the *controller* level so that you can be more selective, you could implement instead a custom *controller* convention that does something very similar. Here's a sample for that:

```
public class SomeControllerModelConvention : Attribute, IControllerModelConvention
{
    public void Apply(ControllerModel model)
    {
        foreach (var actionModel in model.Actions)
            actionModel.Filters.Add(new AuthorizeFilter(actionModel.ActionName));
    }
}
```

This is very similar to `SomeActionModelConvention`, except for these three differences:

1. It implements [IControllerModelConvention](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.applicationmodels.icontrollermodelconvention?view=aspnetcore-2.1) and, as such, is called for each controller rather than for each action.
2. [`Apply`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.applicationmodels.icontrollermodelconvention.apply?view=aspnetcore-2.1#Microsoft_AspNetCore_Mvc_ApplicationModels_IControllerModelConvention_Apply_Microsoft_AspNetCore_Mvc_ApplicationModels_ControllerModel_) is handed a `ControllerModel`, so we iterate through all of its actions and apply the `AuthorizeFilter` to those.
3. It extends `Attribute` so that it can be applied as an attribute.

When using this approach, the convention does *not* need to be added in `Startup.ConfigureServices` - instead, it can be added as an attribute. e.g.:

```
[Route("api/[controller]")]
[ApiController]
[SomeControllerModelConvention]
public class UniversityController : ControllerBase
    ...
```

Finally, if you want to apply the convention to controllers but do so using code, you could register the convention in `Startup.ConfigureServices` (as with the `SomeActionModelConvention` approach) and then customise the implementation of `Apply` to only add the filter according to your own logic. I won't go into the details of that as I've already gone on for long enough.

Comment: Thanks for your reply @KirkLarkin. It saved me. Both of your suggession worked perfectly. But, I could't choose one of them. Which one should I prefer? And Which one is customizable in future of project? What is your idea for my  situation ?

Comment: I would go with `SomeControllerModelConvention` if I knew that all of the actions within a controller would use the action name as the policy name. You can apply this on a per-controller basis (which is useful if some controllers don't need authorisation, for example) or, if you know it's used for *all* controllers in your project, you can just register it as a convention as I described.

Comment: Thanks again @KirkLarkin. For example loginController don't need authorisation as you said. So, SomeControllerModelConvention is more useful in this situation.